# Duplicate "Possible Duplicate" box

Tags: bug, status-completed, closing, exact-duplicates

Amusingly, the question
[Is there a subfield F of the complex field with [C:F]=3?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25999), which was closed as a duplicate, has two "Possible Duplicate" boxes, each indicating the same question as the possible duplicate (namely, [What is the condition for a field to make the degree of its algebraic closure over it infinite?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23729/what-is-the-condition-for-a-field-to-make-the-degree-of-its-algebraic-closure-ove)). Is this a bug of some sort? Obviously it's not a pressing matter, but I thought it should be brought to someone's attention.

Comment: Oh the irony... :-D

Comment: If you look at the edit history, there are two edits by the community user with the description "insert possible duplicate link", one at 16:11 and one at 16:53. Since Qiaochu left a comment at 16:10, I presume he closed the question right after leaving that comment, reopened it afterwards and closed the question again at 16:53.

Comment: I guess I don't have enough rep to see the edit history you're referring to (the bottom of the question where that would usually be looks blank to me) - but that sounds like a plausible explanation.

Comment: @Zev: [Have a gander.](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/25999/revisions)

Comment: @J.M., thanks! I guess that doesn't appear as a "standard" edit history because the edits were made by the community user. Is there a link to that page from somewhere on the question, or did you have to know to add "/revisions" to the end of the URL?

Comment: I think, if I remember correctly, that when something is closed as duplicate, and then re-opened, the automatically inserted link is not automatically removed?

Comment: @Zev: I have to say Theo's comment gave me the idea that adding the `/revisions` part works even on "unedited" stuff...

Comment: @Zev: My answer to another question is related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto/1776#1776  You can always view the revision history as J.M. says, but the direct link only appears after non-Community edits.  (A similar trick works on MathOverflow, e.g., http://mathoverflow.net/revisions/7233/list, as mentioned in tip 5 at http://mathoverflow.net/tips .)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might have been a duplicate action taken during a deployment which caused a race condition on close.

Anyway, all that is needed is to edit the post, which I did.

Comment: Quote: "all that is needed is to edit the post". Good to know. I wasn't sure whether doing so would be effective. So I can just manually go in and remove the extra duplicate box?

Comment: I did not want to edit and bump a closed question, however it happened again: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36129/ in case you want to chase down this bug or something.

Comment: @asaf not a bug, it was reopened and re-closed. Check the revision history. http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/36129/revisions

Comment: Oh. Sorry :-)